# Print dbConnect exception in R?

Tags: r

Using RPostgreSQL and getting an exception on dbConnect:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) :
RS-DBI driver: (could not connect ...)
Calls: dbConnect -> dbConnect -> postgresqlNewConnection -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Looking for a way to catch the error reported by the database engine. dbGetexception requires a connection object, so its no use when the connection fails.

Is there a way to throw an error that reports what the error message from the DB engine is, so I know *why* the connection failed?

All that is needed to generate an error, either with an unavailable server, or bad user or DB name is:

```
library('RPostgreSQL')
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host= "***", dbname = "***", user="***")
```

Comment: So you were connected before this? Could you show a little more of your code?

Comment: Not connected before, this is this is the initial connection,in the opening stub of a new program. In this case the DB engine was configured with a limited connection pool, and the DB error was "no connections available". Would like the R script to report that so we can see from the script *why* the connection fails.

Comment: See this excellent answer on how to use [trycatch()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) in R. Also, that may be a `RPostgreSQL` issue not giving specific info because `RMySQL` error raises: *Unknown MySQL Server Host '***'*

Comment: @MattK if you have an ODBC name that's probably an easier way to connect. If not, validate the architecture compatibility (i.e. 32-bit DB's need 32-bit R, etc), credentials, etc. Try to login on the command line outside of R. You can probably get at the problem this way.

Comment: @Parfait - That is useful information. I will ping the RPostgreSQL mail list to see if this is unique to the PosrgreSQL driver.